# Can you use "Death from Below" from a ladder?

Tags: far-cry-3

I'm trying to infiltrate the `Nostalgia` by the stern ladder. I just put a point in `Death from below` and thought that this was as good a time as any to try it out. However, I can't seem to execute it. The guard is standing close enough for me to see his chest hair and still I cant do anything. Instead I have to climb up in plain sight and hope to dodge a spray of bullets. Not so much "infiltration" as going "head first - guns blazing".

Isn't Death from below usable from ladders?

Comment: I know that *Death from below* can be used from the water, but I don't know about ladders...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, no, you cannot. Death from Below is only usable from ledges in that you have to stand on the ground to be able to use it.